# How can I do an MVC RedirectToAction where I specify the view and a parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to redirect to the following redirect:

```
area = User
controller = "Server"
action = "Index"
page = "F222"
```

However I cannot see an overload in RedirectToAction that allows me to add in the Area. Can someone give me an example of how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an Area to the route, use the [overload with routeValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505283%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Server", new {Area = "User", page = "F222"});
```